# cant load jquery-mobile js file to netbeans

Tags: jquery-mobile, netbeans

I have a problem that **netbeans** cant import the jQuery Mobile lib into my html file.
I always get an error **"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"**.

If i'm deleting row 14 the error disappeared. I tried to import different libs and also from CDN or in my computer but the problem persists.

> [image]

Comment: try loading both JS libraries from same CDN.

Comment: Still same problem: http://oi59.tinypic.com/35d8as1.jpg